# (Material UI) Проблема подключения картинки

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Имеется ссылка, которая возвращает случайное изображение *(https://picsum.photos/600/300)*, а также код элемента сетки. Как мне сделать так, чтобы каждый элемент имел разные изображения? Не имею предположений или вариантов как это можно сделать. Можно ли как-то обратиться к этой ссылке несколько раз, а не только один?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Элемент:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Grid, Paper, Typography, ButtonBase, Box } from '@material-ui/core';

const Img = styled('img')({
  width: '320px',
  borderTopLeftRadius: '4px',
  borderTopRightRadius: '4px'
});

export default function GridItem() {
  return (
      <Grid item>
        <Paper sx={{width: 320}}>
          <ButtonBase>
            <Img alt="image" src="https://picsum.photos/600/300"/> // Собственно вот это та и ссылка
          </ButtonBase>
          <Box sx={{p:1}}>
            <Typography variant="subtitle1">Crowd Prediction</Typography>
            <Typography variant="caption">Crowd Predictions in Ford to forecast weekly vehicles sale volumes across business units</Typography>
          </Box>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

Сетка:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Item from './Item';

export default function Body(){
    return(
        <Grid sx={{width: '98%', mt:8}} container>
            <Grid sx={{m: 'auto'}} container spacing={3}>
                <Item/>
                <Item/>
                <Item/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сработало следующим методом: в GridItem создаём `useEffect` и стейт-хук. Далее в `useEffect` делаем запрос на указанный URL `https://picsum.photos/600/300`. Из ответа сохраняем готовую ссылку картинки в стейт-хук, он расположена в `response.request.responseURL`. И далее идёт отрисовка. Получается так:

GridItem.js:

```
function GridItem() {
  const [link, setLink] = React.useState("");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchLink = async () => {
      const response = await axios("https://picsum.photos/600/300");
      setLink(response.request.responseURL);
    };
    fetchLink();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Grid item>
      <Paper sx={{ width: 320 }}>
        <ButtonBase>
          <Img alt="image" src={link} />
        </ButtonBase>
        <Box sx={{ p: 1 }}>
          <Typography variant="subtitle1">Crowd Prediction</Typography>
          <Typography variant="caption">
            Crowd Predictions in Ford to forecast weekly vehicles sale volumes
            across business units
          </Typography>
        </Box>
      </Paper>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError): axios is not defined. Может у вас стоит какой-то установленный npm пакет, который предоставляет axios?

Comment: Конечно, в терминале набрать `npm i axios`. И добавить `import axios from "axios";`

Comment: Я только что скачал этот пакет и всё заработало так, как я и ожидал. Огромнейшее вам спасибо за помощь! Вопрос отмечен найлучшим.